# Перегрузка оператора [] для поиска элемента в списке

Tags: c++, список, перегрузка-операторов

```
template<typename Type>
double & List_Two_Link<Type>::operator[](int Var_for_search)
{
    List_Two_Link * rec = this->pHead;
    for (int i = 0; (i <= this->itAmount) && (rec->itIndex != Var_for_search); i++, rec = rec->pNext)
    {
        if (i == this->itAmount)
        {
            cout << "Object not found" << endl;
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return rec->pDate->Get_Result() // Здесь функция возвращает double;
}

bool Menu(List_Two_Link<Polynom> *& obj)
{
    double Rec = obj[1]; //здесь ошибка 
    ...
}
```

Подскажите как переопределить `operator[]` для двусвязного списка. Пока для кода выше вот такая ошибка вылетает:

> Не существует подходящей функции преобразования из "List_Two_Link" в "double"

Comment: Немного правил... Не совсем понял о чем вы. `pDate`(тип Polynom, в нем есть некоторые значения, которые возвращаются с помощью `Get_Result()`тип double )

Comment: double Rec = obj [1];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оператор `[]` для указателя раскрывается как `*(pointer + index)`
Вот эти записи полностью эквиваленты

```
int *pointer;
pointer[1] = 42;
1[pointer] = 42;
*(pointer + 1) = 42;
*(1 + pointer) = 42;
```

Проблема в том, к чему вы пытаетесь применить 'operator[]'.

`List_Two_Link<Polynom>  *& obj`

Это ссылка на указатель. 
Если расписать строчку

`double Rec = obj[1];`

То получится

`double Rec = *(obj + 1);`

То есть вы смещаете полученный указатель на 1 и разыменовываете его. В результате получается объект типа `List_Two_Link<Polynom>`.
Пути решения два. Первый заключается в том, чтобы изменить сигнатуру функции, и принимать ссылку на объект, а не на указатель на объект.

`bool Menu(List_Two_Link<Polynom>  &obj)`

Второй способ заключается в том, чтобы применять оператор `[]` не у указателю, а к объекту

`double Rec = (*obj)[1];`

Comment: Или как `obj->operator[](1)` :)